# jQuery selector returns empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, global-variables

I'm developing a modal window which renders with `html()` when a button is clicked and delete the modal when clicked outside of the window with `remove()`.

I'm trying to make this piece of code reusable for multiple modal windows. I declared a global variable `modalWindow` which should define if the window is clicked or not.

This is my code:

```
var modalContent;
var modalContainer = $("#modal-container");
var modalWindow = modalWindow;
var body = $('body');

function pandaModal() {
  modalContent = "<div id='modal'><div id='window'></div></div></div>";
  modalWindow = $('#window');
  openModal();
}

function openModal() {
  modalContainer.html(function() {
    return modalContent;
  });
  var modal = $("#modal");
  body.addClass('noscroll');
  //var modalWindow = $("#window");
  console.log(modalWindow, ' before click');
  $(modalContainer).mouseup(function(e) {
    if (e.target.id != modalWindow.attr('id') && !modalWindow.has(e.target).length) {
      modal.remove();
      body.removeClass('noscroll');
      console.log(modalWindow, ' after click');
    }
  })
}
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
  if (e.which == 27) {
    $("#modal").remove();
    body.removeClass('noscroll');
  }
  e.stopPropagation();
});
$("body").delegate('#counter', 'click', function() {
  pandaModal();
});
```

Here is a codepen example of the issue: http://codepen.io/sanderfish/pen/QyzERM

What happens is when `var modalWindow = $("#window");` remains commented in `openModal`, the selector returns empty. The code works when uncommented, but only for one modal (which is `pandaModal` in this case).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the purpose of modalWindow = modalWindow ?  Why is modalWindow declared as a global variable and then declared again within the function openModal?

Comment: I want to create multiple modals like `pandaModal`, which each contain different `modalContent`s, which returns in having multiple `modalWindows`s. 
`modalWindow` shouldn't be declared again in openModal, it only did that to show what I want to achieve and to show what goes wrong.

Comment: Your code has multiple mistakes. For example, the extra closing div tag in modalContent.  Yet, the more serious problem is that the code tries to select objects before the are created, e.g., modalWindow = $('#window') when it appears to be created in the statement afterward. I'm not sure of the exact problem, but I would guess that this is part of it.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I think the mistakes occurred because of rebuilding the issue in codepen, at least the extra closing div tag was. I tried multiple things, including what you suggest. I have removed the creation of modalWindow now and only declare the variable, instead of assigning it too early. This hasn't solved the problem yet. Do you have any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out how to fix the problem today and therefore writing it as an answer.

```
modalContainer.html(function() {
    return modalContent;
});
```

rendered after the variable `modalWindow` was declared in `pandaModal`. I found out the code did work when I declared the variable after the `html()` function above.

I rewrote my code as following. First I declared my variables:

```
var modalContent;
var modalContainer = $("#modal-wrapper");
var body = $('body');
var modalWindow;
```

Then I wrote the `.on click` function, to declare the `html` that should be rendered, to declare the `modalWindow` which lives inside the to be rendered `html` and to start the `openModal` function. This looks like this:

```
$("#counter").on('click', function() {
    modalContent = "<div id='modal'><div id='window'></div></div>";
    modalWindow = $("#window");
    openModal();
    return false;
});
```

And then the function to render the modal and the closing functions.

```
function openModal() {

    $("#modal-wrapper").html(modalContent);
    var modal = $("#modal");
    var modalWindow = modal.children('div');

    body.addClass('noscroll');
    modal.center();

    $(modalContainer).mouseup(function(e) {
        if(e.target.id != modalWindow.attr('id') && !modalWindow.has(e.target).length) {
            modal.remove();
            body.removeClass('noscroll');
        }
    });

}
```